# How can I get this interface?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I'm debutant in android and I want to get an interface like this but I couldn't place my linearlayout   interface

[image]

I tried to use a horizontal and a vertical linearlayout but it doesn't work

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"><TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txt1"
                    android:text="AAAAAAAA"/><Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="BE"
                    android:id="@+id/button1"/></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                    android:text="RRRRRRR"/><LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txt3"
                    android:text="JJJJJJJJJJ"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="GO"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Start"
                    android:id="@+id/button3"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Can you help me to correct this code?

Comment: I think you should refer to your interface as UI because the first thing one associates with interface is the programming language construct.

Comment: You have to practice and design different layouts and use their properties and see the changes. For beginners it takes time but we all were beginner a few years back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.Hope this helps you.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="AAAAAAAA"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BE" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="RRRRRRR"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="JJJJJJJJJJ"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GO" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Start" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this use `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="AAAAAAAA"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myl1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="123465" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/myl1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="123465" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Start" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Start" />
</RelativeLayout>
```